# UrlRewriteModule.net and session problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, urlrewriting.net

i have a problem in asp.net web-application.

I'm using UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewrite and it's works fine only when there is no uses of session on page.

for example:
simple page Default.aspx with code:

```
<% Session["some_value"] = "test"; %>
```

If i access it via address

```
http://somesite.net/Default.aspx
```

it's ok, but if i try

```
http://somesite.net/test/
```

i have error:

```
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a
configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that 
System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the 
<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
```

How can i solve that problem?

**UPD:** I found answer [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=357248)

just add two lines in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>

      <remove name="Session"/>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>

    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: +1 good to know! @x2 put that as an answer and you can accept it or mention what else do you want to know on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=357248)

just add two lines in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>

      <remove name="Session"/>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>

    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```